# Wordpress can't fetch the posts from the database after moving to new server

Tags: database, installation

After moving wordpress to a new server , I used the same domain in the old server , it's display "Nothing Found" in the index page , and even can't get the posts in "The most comments" widget , and even in the Admin panel i can't see it but I can see the posts counter (15,000) post , but i can see the posts in wp-posts table .

Answer (score 1):

Multiple things could be going wrong here,if you give some more infomation I can give you better answers here are some things to try.

- Check the wp-config.php to make sure the correct database settings are being used
- If you had permalinks you may want to check for or recheck the .htaccess file
- can you login via example.com/wp-login.php?

Comment: I fixed it by set wp_debug to "true" in wp-config.php , and I found that "Event Calender" plugin is making the problem , I deactivated it and everything works fine now , Thanks :)